# Use checkbox to choose which array(s) to select a random value from in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

**In the fiddle:**

Two random selections (one from each array) are given on clicking the Go button.

**My question:**

I would like to use checkboxes (or similar) to determine which value should be randomised and which should be 'saved'.

**Example:**

- Click Go
- '2' & '6' are given
- Tick a checkbox under '2' to 'save' the value
- Click Go again
- 2 remains, second value is now 4

https://jsfiddle.net/9eekhdyk/

HTML:

```
<input class="btn" type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Go" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="message1" >Random</p>
<p id="message2" >Random</p>
```

JS:

```
function GetValue()
{
var myarray1 = new Array("1","2","3");
var myarray2 = new Array("4","5","6");
var random1 = myarray1[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray1.length)];
var random2 = myarray2[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray2.length)];
document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML=random1;
document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML=random2;
}
```

The example is completely stripped back for simplicity; I would be using it on a larger scale.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this? I changed the HTML a bit to have an additional `<span>` to hold the random value and added an `<input type="checkbox" />` before each checkbox.

Ultimately, I just use the checkboxes to exclude the span from the result set of `document.querySelectorAll` when it is not `:not(:checked)`. Hence, only `span` are handled which are not preceded by a checked checkbox. Then, for of that spans, a random value is assigned.

I also extracted the choosing of the random value into a function, which is only called when a value is actually needed. The `data-message-id` of each span associates the span with the random array, which was put into an own array for index-based access. Thus, for `data-message-id="1"`, `randomArr[0]` is accessed etc.

Please don't hesitate to ask if anything is unclear.

```js
function GetValue()
{
  var myarray1 = new Array("1","2","3");
  var myarray2 = new Array("4","5","6");
  
  const randomArr = [myarray1, myarray2];
  
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".message > input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked) + span"))
  .forEach(function (elem) {
    const id = parseInt(elem.dataset.messageId);
    elem.innerHTML = random(randomArr[id - 1]);
  });
}

function random (arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="message1" class="message">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span data-message-id="1">Random</span>
</p>
<p id="message2" class="message">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span data-message-id="2">Random</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the quick reply!
I'm a newbie to JS so I actually don't understand a lot of that but it does exactly what I asked!

I presume it's scalable?

Comment: @MISQ Glad I could help. It should be scalable with little effort. For example, that's why I introduced the `data-message-id` attributes, created a wrapper array and extracted the random function. If you don't understand any particular part of the code, please ask. (Also, I would be glad if you upvoted/accepted my answer if it was helpful to you).

Comment: I understand it now that I've had chance to work with it. It's working great so far and way more efficient than the code I was previously using - thanks again! Great help. (accepted but can't upvote as low rep!)

Comment: thanks again for your help on this - is there a way to have the same `data-message-id-x` values display in separate divs as well?
i.e.: there are `message1` and `message2` both of which have a checkbox - I'd like to display the same result (`message1a` and `message2a`) in another div as well, only without the checkbox

Comment: @MISQ You could simply add another `...innerHTML` behind the existing one. That should work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a *select* :

```
<select id="choose"> </select>
```

Then create a 2d array of your arrays to choose from:

```
var arrays = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8]
];
```

Then add two options to the select:

```
var select = document.getElementById("choose");
arrays.forEach(function(_,i){
 select.innerHTML += 
  `<option value="${i}" > ${i} </option>`;
 });
```

So now the select contains every array index as an option,
And now were ready to do:

```
function getRandom(){
  var array = arrays[ select.selectedIndex ];
  var result = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/yurenotome/edit?output)